# Filtering a JSON array to display multiple or single key values

Tags: json, swift, codable

This block allows me to select a single currency and return all the API values declared in the model. `id`, `symbol`, `name`, `price`, `marketCap` and so on.

**Interface**

```
let data = rawResponse.data
if let eth = data.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
   let cryptocurrency = item.value.symbol
   return cryptocurrency == "ETH"
}).first {
   print(eth)
}
```

I need the flexibility to return only a single value such as `price`. I could comment out all the properties of the struct except for price but that limits the functionality.

I was told I could compare `let cryptocurrency = item.value.symbol` with `return cryptocurrency == "ETH"`etc but I am not sure how to do accomplish this.

**Model**

```
struct RawServerResponse : Codable {
    var data = [String:Base]()

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let baseDictionary = try container.decode([String:Base].self, forKey: .data)
        baseDictionary.forEach { data[$0.1.symbol] = $0.1 }
    }
}

struct Base : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let symbol : String
    let quotes : [String: Quotes]
}

struct Quotes : Codable {
    let price : Double?
}
```

**JSON**

```
"data": {
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "website_slug": "ethereum", 
        "rank": 2, 
        "circulating_supply": 99859856.0, 
        "total_supply": 99859856.0, 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 604.931, 
                "volume_24h": 1790070000.0, 
                "market_cap": 60408322833.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.09, 
                "percent_change_24h": -2.07, 
                "percent_change_7d": 11.92
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unrelated but if you really need the `id` value as key in `data` then delete the entire `init` method and `CodingKeys` and filter `if let eth = data["1027"]  { ...`

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the question.

Comment: Edited my code. I am now using `let cryptocurrency = item.value.symbol` `return cryptocurrency == "ETH"`. The issue is I need to print out only 1 single value such as `name` or `price`. Main priority now is printing out only single values since that block only allows me to print out every single value that exists in the struct model.

Comment: So you want other value in the model to be set nil?

Comment: @AkshaysinghYaduvanshi I want them to be available if needed e.g. for different UI element or whatever. I want the ability to print all the values from the struct or print just one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter an array and display a single value (or in your case find Ethereum and use the price) you can do this:

```
let ethPrice = rawResponse.data.filter({ $0.value.symbol == "ETH" }).first?.price
```

You made it too complicated.

if this needs to be dynamic you can place it in a function

```
func getPrice(symbol: String) -> Double? {
    return rawResponse.data.filter({ $0.value.symbol == symbol }).first?.price
}
```

You need to think of what you are doing in smaller pieces of work.

Get the object that you want which is this part

```
let item = rawResponse.data.filter({ $0.value.symbol == symbol }).first
```

Then you have access to all of the properties of that one object.

If you wanted to print the name and price of all items you can do that quite easily also

```
for item in rawResponse.data {
    print("\(item.symbol) - \(item.price)"
}
```

Comment: You can use `array.first(where: { ... })` instead of filtering then taking `first`

Comment: Thanks Dan.  Via Apple docs determined it is something like `let item = rawResponse.data.first(where: ((key: String, value: Base)) throws -> Bool`. How would it be implemented in my case? Thanks

Comment: @Scriptable Because of how my model is built I had to do `let ethPrice = rawResponse.data.filter({ $0.value.symbol == "ETH" }).first?.value.quotes["USD"]?.price` For the other one I did  something like `let item = rawResponse.data.filter({ $0.value.name == "Bitcoin" }).first` p.s. I was able to comment out the init and CodingKeys enum in my model.

Comment: Yeah the init shouldn't be needed unless you are handling some strange case really. coding keys default values normally work ok

Comment: @Dan mentioned the `.first(where: (key: --, value: -- ))?` method. How is it different? In my case what would be the syntax? Something like `let z = rawResponse.data.first(where: (key: String, value: Base ))`?  I know it takes the first item in the collection where a key is A and a value is B but how would it perform differently? Could someone add that version so myself and others can see it in action? Thanks

Comment: that line doesn't even look like it would compile... `let z = arr.first(where: <#T##(test) throws -> Bool#>)`. as you can see the format is where test. test is a condition. you could do `rawResponse.data.first({ $0.value.symbol == "ETH" }).price` but there isn't much difference

Comment: I was just talking about the use of that method and whether or not it can be used as another solution in my code i.e. `rawResponse.data.first(where: ` as documented here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1848649-first

Comment: yes you can, I gave an example in my last comment on how you can use it :)